# Produce Option<Vec<String>> out of an Option<Vec<Custom>> in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do the equivalent of Ruby's `Enumerable.collect()` in Rust.

I have an `Option<Vec<Attachment>>` and I want to create a `Option<Vec<String>>` from it, with `String::new()` elements in case of `None` guid.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Attachment {
    pub guid: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let ov: Option<Vec<Attachment>> =
        Some(vec![Attachment { guid: Some("rere34r34r34r34".to_string()) },
                  Attachment { guid: Some("5345345534rtyr5345".to_string()) }]);

    let foo: Option<Vec<String>> = match ov {
        Some(x) => {
            x.iter()
                .map(|&attachment| attachment.guid.unwrap_or(String::new()))
                .collect()
        }
        None => None,
    };
}
```

The error in the compiler is clear:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>: std::iter::FromIterator<std::string::String>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:18
   |
15 |                 .collect()
   |                  ^^^^^^^ the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>`
   |
   = note: a collection of type `std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::string::String`
```

If I remember what I've read from the documentation so far, I cannot implement traits for `struct` that I don't own.

How can I do this using `iter().map(...).collect()` or maybe another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read and memorize all of the methods on [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) (and [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html)). These are used *so pervasively* in Rust that knowing what is present will help you immensely.

For example, your `match` statement is [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map).

Since you never said you *couldn't* transfer ownership of the `String`s, I'd just do that. This will avoid any extra allocation:

```
let foo: Option<Vec<_>> =
    ov.map(|i| i.into_iter().map(|a| a.guid.unwrap_or_else(String::new)).collect());
```

Note we don't have to specify the type inside the `Vec`; it can be inferred.

You can of course introduce functions to make it cleaner:

```
impl Attachment {
    fn into_guid(self) -> String {
        self.guid.unwrap_or_else(String::new)
    }
}

// ...

let foo: Option<Vec<_>> = ov.map(|i| i.into_iter().map(Attachment::into_guid).collect());
```

If you don't want to give up ownership of the `String`, you can do the same concept but with a string slice:

```
impl Attachment {
    fn guid(&self) -> &str {
        self.guid.as_ref().map_or("", String::as_str)
    }
}

// ...    

let foo: Option<Vec<_>> = ov.as_ref().map(|i| i.iter().map(|a| a.guid().to_owned()).collect());
```

Here, we have to use [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) to avoid moving the `guid` out of the `Attachment`, then convert to a `&str` with [`String::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str), providing a default value. We likewise don't take ownership of the `Option` of `ov`, and thus need to iterate over references, and ultimately allocate new `String`s with `ToOwned`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Attachment {
    pub guid: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let ov: Option<Vec<Attachment>> =
        Some(vec![Attachment { guid: Some("rere34r34r34r34".to_string()) },
                  Attachment { guid: Some("5345345534rtyr5345".to_string()) }]);

    let foo: Option<Vec<_>> = ov.map(|x|
        x.iter().map(|a| a.guid.as_ref().unwrap_or(&String::new()).clone()).collect());

    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

One of the issues with the above code is stopping the `guid` being moved out of the `Attachment` and into the vector. My example calls `clone` to move cloned instances into the vector.

This works, but I think it looks nicer wrapped in a trait impl for `Option<T>`. Perhaps this is a better ... option ...:

```
trait CloneOr<T, U>
    where U: Into<T>,
          T: Clone
{
    fn clone_or(&self, other: U) -> T;
}

impl<T, U> CloneOr<T, U> for Option<T>
    where U: Into<T>,
          T: Clone
{
    fn clone_or(&self, other: U) -> T {
        self.as_ref().unwrap_or(&other.into()).clone()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Attachment {
    pub guid: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let ov: Option<Vec<Attachment>> =
        Some(vec![Attachment { guid: Some("rere34r34r34r34".to_string()) },
                  Attachment { guid: Some("5345345534rtyr5345".to_string()) },
                  Attachment { guid: None }]);

    let foo: Option<Vec<_>> =
        ov.map(|x| x.iter().map(|a| a.guid.clone_or("")).collect());

    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

Essentially the unwrapping and cloning is hidden behind a trait implementation that attaches to `Option<T>`.

[Here it is running on the playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=cd9ff434c7f5eae5eae0651cc562802c&version=stable).

Comment: `and_then` with a hardcoded `Some` doesn't really make sense; should just be `map`, no?

Comment: *You have to clone* — not **have**, but "can", perhaps.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that you'd be creating each string twice; once in the call to `String::new`, and then again with the `clone`. It's not terrible for an empty `String`, as there's no heap allocation, but in general it's odd.

Comment: Oh of course :/ I will change it to `map`. Perhaps I will rephrase the "have to" part as well.